# PHP Code viewable on website?

Tags: php, file, foreach

Why is the below code displaying the php code from msg.php?

```
$flag = file('msg.php');
$content = "";
foreach ($flag as $value) {
    $content .= $value;
}
echo $content;
```

Is there a way I can stop it displaying the PHP code?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're outputting it as text with `echo` and reading it with `file`, neither of which will execute any PHP. Your example can be replaced with:

```
require 'msg.php';
```

and everything will work properly.

Comment: @zerkms: No. There could be a syntax error in the file, which is being executed through the CLi and a redirected STDERR that creates a virus upon receiving output that mutates and wipes out 99% of the population.

Comment: Well, apart from all that (which we don't know), at least `$flag` is not set with your suggestion which has been set earlier.

Comment: @minitech: oh, I've misread your answer as "replace `file()` with `require`", sorry

Answer (score 1):

Here's some things to check:

- Do you have the code wrapped in `<?php   ?>` tags?
- Does the filename end with .php?

If both of these are the case, your server might not be setup to handle PHP correctly.

Also what is the content of msg.php? If it contains php code, that could be what is getting output, since you are just reading it in and then echoing it out without running the interpreter on it.

Answer (score 1):

you should assign value to `$flag` inside msg.php and include the file.

```
include 'msg.php'
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the last `echo`. `echo` prints the content on screen.

Answer (score 0):

If you're meaning the contents of the file msg.php has PHP code in it and that is what is displaying, that is because your doing simply that. Out putting PHP as text.

The PHP code is treated as text as it has not been processed by the server. You will have to filter out the PHP by finding the opening and closing PHP tags but I suspect you want the code to execute in which case you need to include the file.

Answer (score -1):

You probably do not have the `<?php ?>` tags wrapping your code. If you do, then php is not setup right on your server.